# How do I resize my partition on my Mac?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

[image: Disk utility OS X Mavericks]

I'm having trouble resizing my hard drive partition. Before, I was running OS X Lion in the free space above Macintosh HD 2. Now that I deleted the Lion partition, I am unable to resize Macintosh HD 2 to the full capacity of my hard drive.

Comment: I find this very annoying, as well, plus the problem still exists on Yosemite. I've upvoted your question.

Comment: tbh, any task like this is one for [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com/iPartition/) unless you have a Logical Volume Group or Drobo